# Tips for developing Penlets

Tags: java, java-me, pen, livescribe

Finally I have time to do some projects for fun. I want to write some app for my new [Livescripe Pulse smart pen](http://www.livescribe.com/).

Has anybody out there already written something like this? Do You have any tips for beginner or useful links? I am having trouble finding sites for penlets, anymore!

Comment: How about the small samples her http://www.livescribe.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2167 and documentation here http://www.livescribe.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1537

Comment: I will definitely check it. But also I would like to hear about coders experiences.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I found better answer - "do not develop penlets" - http://www.kellbot.com/2011/06/livescribe-developer-community-huge-f-you/ :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides obvious sources (like [penlets.com](http://penlets.com/tutorials/penlets_101/)), there seems to be an [interesting Wordpress blog](http://en.wordpress.com/tag/livescribe-programming/), and a [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/penlets) (which are often helpful).

Comment: nothing from these is not helpful anymore :(